# В базе есть числовое значение, как при выборке заменить это чисо на строку?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

в бд есть числовые значения 0-2.

Хотелось бы при выборке заменять

```
0 на Администратор
1 - Помощник
2 - Остальные
```

Как это реализовать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете выполнить [мутацию в модели](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator), если хотите прям заменять. Например, для поля `group` можно сделать что-то такое:

```
public function getGroupAttribute()
{
    $groups = [
       'Администратор',
       'Помощник',
       'Остальные',
    ];

    return $groups[ $this->attributes['group'] ];
}
```

Но это плохой вариант, который годится только как временное решение (нарушение принципа открытости-закрытости как минимум).

В Вашем варианте лучше было бы создать таблицу в БД, которая содержит роли (`groups`: `id`, `title`), а в Вашей текущей таблице ссылаться на id роли (`group_id`). В модели Вашей текущей таблицы завести отношение:

```
public function group()
{
    $this->hasOne(Group::class, 'group_id');
}
```

При получении данных забирать группу по `->with('group')`.
Подробнее об отношениях можно почитать [здесь](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships).

Comment: Спасибо большое, но у меня всего 3 значения будет и добавляться/меняться они не будут